# Finding the number of occurrences of a specific string in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm trying to count the number of words that have the string: "hanger" from the column "Description". So I defined a function:

```
def hanger_count(title): 
if 'hanger' in title.lower().split():
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Which seemed to be working correctly when I tested it with a string. But when I attempted to run the function through the data column, using the function:

```
ecomm['Description'].apply(hangercount)
```

I received an error back:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I think the issue is that python is seeing some of the rows in the column as objects rather than strings, is there any way I can convert it?

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have mixed data types in your column, and since `lower()` is only a method for strings, you are getting an error when pandas attempts to call the function on a numeric value (in this case a float).

This quick tweak might work for you:

```
def hanger_count(title): 
    if 'hanger' in str(title).lower().split():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do the following using `str.contains()` and `count()`:

```
df[df['Description'].str.contains('hanger', case=False, na=False)].count()
```

Comment: Probably also add `case=False` to `.str.contains`